# Mystery right-hugging webpage

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out why my web pages are hugging the right. I assumed it needed a float cleared somewhere, but after going into every section to clear it, nothing changes. It's most obvious on mobile size. You can see an example at http://www.grettagoldstein.com/design.html

Any ideas?

HTML for my list items (the whole page is a list for my portfolio):

```
<ul class="flex-container"> 

    <a href="roundtable.html"><li class="flex-item">
        <div class="box" >
            <img src="images/roundtablethumb-goldstein.jpg">
            <div class="box-content">
                <h3 class="title">Roundtable Flyers</h3>
                <span class="post">Chicago Transit Authority</span>
            </div>
        </div></li></a>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the padding off the page UL flex container.

```
<ul class="flex-container" style="
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
">
```

That fixes it.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it perfectly.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure.